# C++ how to check if cin does not equal something in a while loop condition?

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I am trying to learn file i/o in c++. I have a bunch of variables like kill, death, assist, result, notes and I want to enter them into a text file. I have seen tutorials where they use cin inside a while loop like

```
while ( cin >> kill >> death >> assist ) {
file << kill << death << assist ; }
```

but I want the user to type in "done" when they are done entering their input.
I know in python you can do something like

```
while (input != "done" ):
     //code//
```

can I do something similar?

```
while ( cin >> () != "done" ) {
cin >> kill >> death >> assist >> notes ;
file << kill << death << assist << notes ; }
```

Comment: For one, try `operator >>` .

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple conditions using the logical AND and OR operators.

You can also use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read a line, and then use an [input string stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to parse the input.

For example something like:

```
std::string input;
while (std::getline(cin, input) && input != "done")
{
    std::istringstream is(input);
    is >> kill >> death >> assist;
    ...
}
```

The expression in the condition reads a while line, checks that there was no errors or end-of-file when reading, and then check that the input was not `"done"`.

Comment: Thank you i will try that and read up on input string stream.

Comment: I recommend always checking input succeeds before using the variables you tried to read into, as in `if (is >> kill >> death >> assist)` *...use them...* `; else` *...handle the error / input line didn't contain kill, death and assist...* `;`.

Comment: @TonyD yeah I am gonna make sure the inputs are actually what they are supposed to be but I simply wanted to know if it was possible to write a conditional statement using cin inside a while loop because none of the tutorial I looked at used that method ( maybe because it's not efficient.).